# cookies php and javascript update value for next new value

Tags: php

I Create cookies by Js and i get the value by php $_COOKIE[ItemsName] so I can filter the model Items by 
items name the problem next row the cookies not update the value

here is my code

```
function GetDX2(Z)
{
    // onchange items id ="Items_"+Z    
    //document.getElementById("Items_"+Z).value    
    //.innerHTML

    var x =document.getElementById("Items_"+Z).value;

    document.cookie="ItemsName="+x+";";

    document.getElementById("ModelList").innerHTML="<?php   $sql="select * from products where warehouseID='$_POST[currentchanged]' and Items='$_COOKIE[ItemsName]'"; $dd=mysql_query($sql,$conn); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($dd)){echo "<option value='$row[Model]'> $row[Items]</option>";} setcookie("ItemsName", "$_COOKIE[ItemsName]", "1/1/2003");?>";
}
```

---

here the input jquery

```
function addRow() {
$('table#myTable').dataTable().fnAddData( [
 '<center><input type="text" name="sn_' + count + '" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width: 20px" value="'+ccx+'"> <input type="hidden" name="SNX" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width: 20px" value="'+count+'"></center>',

'<center><select name="warehouse_' + count + '" id="warehouse_' + count + '" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width: 200px"  onchange="GetWARE(' + count + ')"><?php $sql="select * from warehouselist"; $d=mysql_query($sql,$conn);   if($_POST["currentchanged"]!=""){echo "<option>$_POST[currentchanged]</option>";} while($row=mysql_fetch_array($d)){echo "<option>$row[Name]</option>";}  ?></select>',

  '<center><input type="text" name="Items_' + count + '" id="Items_' + count + '" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width: 300px" list="ItemsList" autocomplete="off" onchange="GetDX2(' + count + ')">',

   '<center><input type="text" name="ItemsM_' + count + '" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width: 200px" autocomplete="off" list="ModelList">',
   '<center><input type="text" name="Des_' + count + '" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width: 390px">',
   '<center><input type="text" name="Qty_' + count + '" id="Qty_' + count + '" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width: 50px" value="1" onchange="PricC(' + count + ')">',
   '<center><input type="text" name="Price_' + count + '" id="Price_' + count + '" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width: 50px" onchange="PricC(' + count + ')">',
  '<center><input type="text" name="Total_' + count + '" id="Total_' + count + '" style="border-style: solid; border-width: thin; width: 50px">' ] );

count++;
ccx++;
 document.getElementById("LOOPN").value= count;    
}
```

Comment: PHP is running in server side and javascript in client side. The order is first execute PHP and later JavaScript. So, with your code doesnt do what you want

Comment: You need to put everything inside in $_POST and $_COOKIE into single or double quote. Like: `$_COOKIE["ItemsName"]` Without that, theye are constants.

Comment: it this not effected with or without quote the problem php code red old value from cookie but js in every time i press add row update the cookies value

Comment: I try to create invoice where you select the warehouse datalist filter by warehouse you selected the when you select items model datalist filter by items you selected if i use post i will lose the current value and number of row that user entered if there example please help me thanks

Comment: I suggest use AJAX to do that